# win32 Outlook send Mail with sendkeys

Tags: python, winapi, outlook, sendkeys

I currently have a working script that finished with sending an E-Mail. However it is always necessary to manually confirm the sending by clicking on the allow button in the confirmation window.

My goal is to press the allow button automatically.

My current script:

```
def send_notification():
 outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
 mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
 mail.To = 'xxx@xx.com'
 mail.Subject = 'xxx'
 mail.HTMLBody = body_all
 mail.send
```

Any idea how I can confirm the window in the code?
I also tried to use mail.Display instead of mail.send, but both will stop the code waiting to confirm the window before perfoming code that eventually would follow (like sendkeys or similar).

Many thanks in advance,
Best regards

Richard

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

```
def send_notification():
 outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
 shell = win32.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
 mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

 mail.To = 'xx@xx.com'
 mail.Subject = 'xx'
 mail.HTMLBody = body_all
 mail.Display()
 shell.AppActivate("Outlook")
 sleep(1)
 shell.SendKeys("%s", 0)
```